# не пойму что означает эта ошибка

Tags: java, configuration

написал код, сделал конфиг, запускаю из командной строки, а он мне выдает следующее

```
io.dropwizard.configuration.ConfigurationValidationException: service\config\cds.yml has an error:
```

* enclave.iasSecretKey ╨╜╨╡ ╨╝╨╛╨╢╨╡╤В ╨▒╤Л╤В╤М ╨┐╤Г╤Б╤В╨╛

```
    at io.dropwizard.configuration.BaseConfigurationFactory.validate(BaseConfigurationFactory.java:238)
    at io.dropwizard.configuration.BaseConfigurationFactory.build(BaseConfigurationFactory.java:128)
    at io.dropwizard.configuration.BaseConfigurationFactory.build(BaseConfigurationFactory.java:89)
    at io.dropwizard.cli.ConfiguredCommand.parseConfiguration(ConfiguredCommand.java:126)
    at io.dropwizard.cli.ConfiguredCommand.run(ConfiguredCommand.java:74)
    at io.dropwizard.cli.Cli.run(Cli.java:78)
    at io.dropwizard.Application.run(Application.java:93)
    at org.whispersystems.contactdiscovery.ContactDiscoveryService.main(ContactDiscoveryService.java:83)
```

мой конфиг

enclave:
  spid:        2327390F4B50339DA95FE95C4C17B640

iasHost:    https://api.trustedservices.intel.com/sgx/dev

iasSecretKey: 3374e3708d5c43b3bc6f087a34750bda

acceptGroupOutOfDate: false

что это все значит? вот эти непонятные символы

Comment: `╨╜╨╡ ╨╝╨╛╨╢╨╡╤В ╨▒╤Л╤В╤М ╨┐╤Г╤Б╤В╨╛` это `не может быть пусто` (CP866 -> UTF-8) :)

Comment: а как это исправить не подскажите? ведь у меня там не пусто

Answer (score 1):

Строка считывается с некорректной кодировкой.
В выводе кодировка CP866. Я бы проверил кодировку файла конфигурации, убедился, что там используется UTF-8.

Comment: ну кодировка не очень интересна мне, мне интересно как саму ошибку убрать, пишет что строка в конфиге не может быть пустой, но она не пустая, я с такой ошибкой раньше не сталкивался и не пойму как это исправить?